# javascript find a random occurred string inside a string

Tags: javascript

I need to search and find the exact image url from a webpage source wth javascript.

Currently I can only count the occurrences.

My code is:

```
var count = 0;
var pos = res.body.indexOf("650x365");
while(pos > -1){
    ++count;
    pos = res.body.indexOf("650x365", ++pos);
}
console.log(count);    // 2
```

url is like this

```
http://img.sa.com/c/1/70/650x365/bp/02112015_esa.jpg
```

Comment: What is res variable?

Comment: source code of a webpage I need to find image url

Comment: Can you show html where this url is present? Also, you need the whole url or some part of it?

Comment: not needed the mage url is this from any content ,,,http://img.sa.com/c/1/70/650x365/bp/02112015_esa.jpg image name is changing only

Comment: How did you populate res variable?

Comment: How res.body looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex of some kind, here's an example that makes some assumptions about the url:

```
var urls = res.body.match(/http:\/\/img\.sa\.com\/c\/\d+\/\d+\/650x365\/bp\/.+?\.jpg/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// vanilla js
function imagesByString(_string) {
    var images =  document.querySelectorAll('img');
    var matched = [];
    images.forEach(function(image) {
        if (image.getAttribute('src').indexOf(_string) !== -1) {
            matched.push(image.getAttribute('src'));
        }
   });

   return matched;
}

// usage (returns array of image links/sources)
console.log(imagesByString('something_to_find');
```